# Extracting hydrogen from a star

Tags: technology, science-fiction, space, spaceships

How could you feasibly extract hydrogen from a star to power a plasma fusion reactor, with as little handwavium as possible? This takes place in a sci-fi setting, but isn't necessarily hard science. The more realistic it is, the better, but don't feel afraid to stretch physics a bit. The hydrogen would be collected by large colony ships, so size of extraction hardware isn't much of an issue.

Comment: On Stargate Universe the Destiny could recharge its engines on stars.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpvq5wXeeos

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract it from a gas giant?

Comment: Yes, it might be, but stars are far more common, and also it sounds cooler. :) also gas giants aren't always hydrogen

Comment: The easier thing would be not trying to get gas from the star to power a fusion reactor but just let the star do the fusing and taking the energy.

Comment: The idea would be to use the hydrogen for ejection mass, as well, so it would serve a double purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solar flares. Since they are not absolutely understood, perhaps they can be somehow manipulated. See [EJECTION OF HYDROGEN AND IONIZED CALCIUM ATOMS WITH HIGH VELOCITY AT THE TIME OF SOLAR FLARES* HELEN W. DODSON, E. RUTH ...](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1953ApJ...117...66D)